# Puppeteer won't load page from laravel exec() in controller

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, puppeteer

Laravel 5.6 running on 127.0.0.1:8000

i have an file capture.js who use Puppeteer and opens page

127.0.0.1:8000/render

when i call it from command line it works very well.

```
node capture.js
```

now when i call it inside a laravel controller using

```
exec('node capture.js' )
```

it launches Puppeteer, but the page does not load (TIMEOUT)

when i try from the controller with capture.js loading another page ( ex : google.fr ) it works well.

does it have something to do with network ? localhost on port 8000 ?

headless false or true gave same results => TIMEOUT

Comment: How about other executables? How about just launching a browser? Is the code running with the same user, environment and privileges?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Everything is fine, actually puppeteer launches, just unable to load this specific page from  localhost port 8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `exec` from a file which is needed to start your laravel app. It's getting timed out because exec is blocking the laravel app to boot up.

This is an example of what's being done,

Laravel App -> Puppeteer -> Wait! Go fetch Laravel App

Comment: Thanks. actually the laravel app is already running, Solved by rendering the page outside the laravel context, with express serving on port 3000.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue on a Symfony 3.4 project.

The problem came from the sessions:

When the exec() command is called, a PHP session already exist and the session file is locked.
And when the NodeJS script try to connect, there is a timeout, because session file is not available.

I solved the problem by adding the following instruction above the exec() command:

```
session_write_close();
```